# Which sub navigation pattern on a tabbed pageable ActionBar main navigation for Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone of you know of a sub navigation pattern in Android that uses a tabbed ActionBar navigation with pageable Fragments for its main navigation? (ViewPager)

I have looked at Spinners in the ActionBar which could work quite well if it wouldn't take ages to get the submenu rendered in the ActionBar while swiping from one tab to the next. (in the end you have jumping action items which look pretty ugly)

The other approach would include a segmented control widget which is known from the iOS platform. (like the TED application has it at the moment)

But what would be the Android way of doing it?

Comment: Like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-3_o2DIUhbeM/Tsm9PMIR6ZI/AAAAAAAAArs/AYn1hRjIRX8/device-2011-11-20-213516.png)? I'm not exactly sure what you're describing.

Comment: Well no. What you are showing in the picture is the main navigation. (build with tabs) But what about having a sub navigation for lets say "ARTISTS". What would be the Android way of doing such a sub navigation? (I mentioned two ways that come to my mind. The first one is pretty ugly when using pageable tabs and the second one doesn't feel like Android - copying the segmented control widget of iOS)

Comment: With segmented controls I mean something like this: http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/wiki/SegmentedControl or this http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/segmented-control-2

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think this depends entirely on implementation, and on device. In one of my apps, one of my tabs has two buttons on it for a phone (which each link to an `Activity`), and in the tablet version these open a `Fragment` on the right hand side. I do believe a similar behavior can be seen in the ICS/JB Gmail and People apps. So, I think this all depends on the content you wish to display in the segmented navigation.

Comment: Yeah well the content I want to display needs a Tab navigation for its main content. That's why I'm using the ActionBar tab navigation mode. Now I'm thinking about my sub categories for the different tabs. At the moment I am prefering a segmented control widget which seems the best for sub navigation below a tab bar. My prefered way would be a dropdown in the ActionBar (I would split the bar to the bottom) but while swiping left and right (swiping the tabs) the additional action bar actions don't get inflated and added fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try menu's for different tabs? I dont know whether it helps or not.Surf google for creating menus for each tab.